# How to get easting and northing values in android

Tags: android, location

I have retrieved the user location (lat /latidtude) using `LocationListener`
Now i need to get the easting and northing values. is thr any way to do it,
I have already found a library called jcoord. But what it does is, it converts the easting and northing to lat/lng . but i need the other way around.

Is there any way to do it . Thanks

Comment: you can probably write the logic yourself. It shouldn't be too complicated. Try searching for the algorithm on Google/SO. Don't think Android provides in-built methods for that.

Comment: @SamarthJain Jain Does the UTM and easting and northing are same?? cause as i know they are same.

Comment: please specify exactly what you understand in easting and northing! your question is not well formulated. Do you want UTM coordiates, which have a easting and northing value? or do you want an east north difference between two coordinates?

Comment: @AlexWien i need to have easting and northing values for a given lat/lng value

Comment: this is still not precise. the term easting is not unique. please find out in what context easting is meant. an utm easting or an LantLong easting; show examples for a lat,long coordinate given in degrees with its coresponding easting, northing value

Comment: i have followed the folllowing link, but im not sure whether the values are correct or not   https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/viWueEjB1Ds